# Access Blocked: authorisation error. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I just released my first app and It has a button in it that takes you to a website.
A user just sent me this:[image: google error].

I tried googling Google's secure browsers policy but not much info is coming up.
how can I make my app comply with this policy? I think the button opens a browser in app (I use duckduckgo as my default browser and haven't had an issue)

is it just a case of opening a browser and then heading to the website when the button is pressed?
my code to open the website is:

```
_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://www.thiswebsite.com';
  final uri = Uri.parse(url);
  if (await canLaunchUrl(uri)) {
    await launchUrl(uri);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

thanks so much and any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is trying to make sure, you open this window in an actual new browser window, not in a webview still under the control of your application.

Your code *should* open an external browser.

Maybe the user has no browser installed on their device? Maybe their default browser is some exotic thing not recognized by Google?

If you are using the latest version of `url_launcher` (currently 6.1.8) there is not a lot more you can do.

You could *force* the app to take the external browser, not the in-app webview:

```
await launchUrl(_url,mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication);
```

But that should be what happens anyway. If your version is up to date, ask your user, what browser they use. Be prepared to tell them that they need to use another one.